# Excel Issue- custom format for Turkish currency

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, currency-formatting, custom-formatting

I need to format a column in excel to adhere to Turkish currency format using the **Custom format** option available in Excel(for Turkish Lira, the decimal separator is comma(,) and thousand separator is dot(.)). I have "#,##0.00\ """"€""""" custom format for Euro currency. Could someone please help in changing this format to conform to the Turkish format? Example for the same is given below:

Value: 1000
Euro Format: 1,000.00 €
Turkish Format: 1.000,00 ₺

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
#.##0,00 [$₺-tr-TR]
```

Where, `#.##0,00 €` would do for Euro's.

[image]